# Vue: Fetched data from API not showing

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm making an e-learning website using Vuetify and axios. Here are my codes

Courses.vue

```
<template>
<div>
  <v-container>
      <v-row>
          <v-col md="3" offset-lg="1">
              <Categories />
          </v-col>
          <v-col md="9" lg="7">
              <CourseList v-bind:courses="courses"/>
          </v-col>
      </v-row>
  </v-container>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import CourseList from '@/components/courses/CourseList.vue'
import Categories from '@/components/courses/Categories.vue'
import axios from 'axios'


export default {
  components: {
    CourseList,
    Categories
  },
  data() {
         return {
            courses: []
         }
  },
  mounted (){
            axios
                .get('https://esl3usx3t7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testing1/api/get_courses')
                .then((res)=>{this.courses = res.data.body})
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
</script>
```

CourseList.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
      <h2>Courses</h2>

      <v-row>
          <v-col sm="6" md="4" v-for="course in courses" v-bind:key="course.courseId">
       
                  <VerticalCard v-bind:course="course"/>
         
          </v-col>
      </v-row>
      
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VerticalCard from '@/components/cards/VerticalCard.vue'

export default {
    name: "CourseList",
    components: {
        VerticalCard
    },
    props: ["courses"]
}
</script>
```

VerticalCard.vue

```
<template>
  <v-card
    outlined
  >
    <v-img
      :src="course.courseImage"
      height="100%"
    />

    <v-card-subtitle class="font-weight-light">
      {{ course.courseCategory}}
    </v-card-subtitle>

    <v-card-title class="subtitle-1 font-weight-bold">
      {{ course.courseTitle }}
    </v-card-title>

    <v-card-subtitle class="font-weight-medium">
      {{ course.creator }}
    </v-card-subtitle>

    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn class="pa-5 primary white--text" text>
          VIEW
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "VerticalCard",
    props:["course"]
}
</script>
```

The data is fetched because it appears when I use the console log. But the cards appear only two, and it doesn't have any content. I wonder what I am doing wrong. I'm new to Vue and I have been working on this problem for two days and still don't know what my fault is. Many thanks to everyone!

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: @anpel nope. if i write {{courses}} in Courses.vue, all the json data appears! also there's no error from my browser's console

Comment: I have tried to explain with as much detail as possible in my answer. Let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually super simple!

So I took a look at your data source at https://esl3usx3t7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testing1/api/get_courses.

It returns a JSON object with `statusCode` and `body`. So in your Courses component you do `this.courses = res.data.body` expecting your actual data is in the body.

The problem is that the body does not contain the data directly, it also has a `statusCode` and a `body` itself, so the two cards you see are those two.

All you have to do is go one level deeper.

```
this.courses = res.data.body.body
```

I created a (simplified) version of your app to demonstrate. See [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-hoq1y?file=/src/components/Courses.vue).